# Optimize SQL Query In Dynamics AX

Tags: sql, dynamics-ax-2012

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM CUSTQUOTATIONJOUR t1
WHERE t1.RECID = (SELECT top 1 MAX(t2.RECID)
                  FROM CUSTQUOTATIONJOUR t2
                  WHERE substring(t2.QUOTATIONDOCNUM,1,8) = substring(t1.QUOTATIONDOCNUM,1,8)
                 )
```

Hi Guys,
Please help me optimize this query.

Comment: There is surely a better field to join on than taking 8 characters out of a substring in the where clause. That's a huge performance hit there. Is there no actual doc number or a key field? Also returning only the necessary columns and not all (*) is a better practice.

Comment: @JacobH there is no other column unfortunately. The docnums are stored e.g. Q12345-1, Q12345-2, Q12345-3 and I am supposed to always return the latest one. I will try returning only the necessary columns.

Comment: Now you see why you should follow the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) when designing data model. Your performance problem is a consequences of the bug in design.

Comment: @MartinDráb Yeah, but when you move to a company which did its design and go live 5 years ago you don't have much control.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Jacob H said in his comment, sometimes optimizing the query means optimizing the table.

Your `CustQuotationJour.QuotationDocNum` field likely is in a format such as `12345678AA` and `12345678BB` or something.

If this were truly the only way to compare, then you should add a new column to contain only the `12345678` part you are comparing on and add to an index.

The in AX business logic, when the `QuotationDocNum` field is populated, you just perform the `subStr()` to store the 8 characters at that time.

Comment: I can unfortunately not change the table. :-( . Let me try and create another view

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I managed. I just created two different views. One where I substring the QUOTATIONDOCNUM and then other view which contains the final selection. Looks like this

```
WITH t2
AS (
    SELECT [QUOTATIONID]
        ,[QUOTATIONDATE]
        ,[SALESID]
        ,[RESPITEDATE]
        ,[ORDERACCOUNT]
        ,[INVOICEACCOUNT]
        ,[CUSTGROUP]
        ,[PURCHASEORDER]
        ,[DELIVERYNAME]
        ,[CUSTOMERREF]
        ,[DLVTERM]
        ,[DLVMODE]
        ,[PAYMENT]
        ,[CASHDISCCODE]
        ,[CASHDISCPERCENT]
        ,[QTY]
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY QUOTATIONDOCNUM ORDER BY recid DESC
            ) AS t1
    FROM [CUSTQUOTATIONJOUR_vw_revised]
    )
SELECT [QUOTATIONID]
    ,[QUOTATIONDATE]
    ,[SALESID]
    ,[RESPITEDATE]
    ,[ORDERACCOUNT]
    ,[INVOICEACCOUNT]
    ,[CUSTGROUP]
    ,[PURCHASEORDER]
    ,[DELIVERYNAME]
    ,[CUSTOMERREF]
    ,[DLVTERM]
    ,[DLVMODE]
    ,[PAYMENT]
    ,[CASHDISCCODE]
    ,[CASHDISCPERCENT]
    ,[QTY]
FROM t2
WHERE t1 = 1;
```